# return value of application(_:openFile:) delegate method in MacOS

Tags: macos, file-association

[application(_:openFile:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428612-application) delegate method is used to handle file association launch in macos.It states the return value as:

> true if the file was successfully opened or false if it was not.

However, I m not very clear about the return value, because clicking the file launched my application either way with application(_:openFile:) getting invoked, irrespective of returning true or false from this delegate?

Can someone explain it better?